# How to adjust the height of the parent div after translateY(-50%)

Tags: html, css

I have a problem while using bootstrap card. I have used the     `transform: translateY(-50%);` for translate the element to the y-axis , I have set the height of the parent div to auto, but the problem is that after translate the element, I want the height should be adjust automatically.

this is the html

```
<div class="card layer-1-left-sub">
    <img class="card-img-top profile-icon" src="images/profile-boy.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

this is my css

```
.layer-1-left-sub{
  padding: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #3f51b5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
  height: auto;
}

.profile-icon{
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

this is the problem I am facing

[image]

**I have a extra space between image and paragraph , I want to remove the extra space**

Comment: you want the picture in the frame?

Comment: You can try this: Set `position: absolute` on your image and set `margin-top` on your paragraph. This is a different approach compared to what you are trying. But, it will be cleaner and work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated with using transform property!

```css
 .layer-1-left-sub{
  padding: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #3f51b5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.profile-icon{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.card-text {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="card layer-1-left-sub" style="margin-top:100px">
    <img class="card-img-top profile-icon" src=" https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/758084549821730820/_HYHtD8F.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I solved your problem. I used Display flex and removed some unnecessary css properties. If you use it this way, you will have a much cleaner styling without having to deal with position absolute

```css
 .layer-1-left-sub{
  padding: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #3f51b5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile-icon{
    margin-top: -80px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
  <div class="card layer-1-left-sub" style="margin-top:100px">
    <img class="card-img-top profile-icon" src=" https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/758084549821730820/_HYHtD8F.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Its not working with the translate, I don't want to set the margin

Comment: you have fixed the margin-top:-80px , can you please make it with translate?

Comment: Why do you want to use transform ? all sizes will remain the same with the styling I wrote.

Comment: that's the requirement actually

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you explain why  ? I mean, he works without a problem. you don't even have to add media query.

Comment: I have to used it with that actually , you are right but that's what I have to do it that way

Comment: if you apply transform to the item and do not apply margin or something to the items in the container, you will never get the result you want. by using transform translate, you move the item out of its normal flow and it does not occupy height in the container. you now ?

Comment: I applied transform and updated the codes as you asked. you have to put a margin on the P label. But this time I did transform. I hope it's alright. I'm not deleting the other codes so you can use whatever you want. you need to use the margin to adjust the container size! Do not forget!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change profile icon `position` to `absolute` and add some padding for the container, since you know the icon size.

```css
.layer-1-left-sub {
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 78px;
  border: 2px solid #3f51b5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
}

.profile-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

I don't know if `card-text` has top margin, so you might want to add that too (or, alternatively, further increase bottom padding for the container).